# kitkat (API 19) inserting contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-4.4-kitkat

After searching almost the whole Internet already I have a really big headache from this problem. I have a code that works on any APIs, in addition to API 19 KitKat (Google Nexus). It is a typical code for **adding/inserting** contacts to device. Anyone have any ideas why this does not work right?

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                appData.getAccount().name);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                appData.getAccount().type);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, user.getName());
        op_list.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                0);
        builder.withValue(
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                user.getName());
        op_list.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                "vnd.android.cursor.item/customMimeType");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, user.getID());
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "Profile");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Send message");
        builder.withValue(Data.DATA10, user.getID());
        op_list.add(builder.build());

        try {
            contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

No exceptions are thrown, but the contact cannot be found in contact list after insert.

Comment: "After searching almost the whole Internet already..." How long did that take?

Comment: On a more serious note, what does "doesn't work" mean? What does your code do and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think that I dont have to tell you it was a joke :) And to your second question that is already answered in last sentece. I want to insert contact to the device, but after running this code the contact is not in system contact list :) But only on API 19 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use DATA3 column (it has LABEL alias for android framework MIME types). And I would change MIMETYPE to something completely different from framework MIME types, like **org.myprog.app/mycustomType**