# New inserted contact disappears after 30 sec

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to insert new contact into the android contacts database on API 19 (KITKAT) into Google contacts account. I use basically the same code as in documentation without any custom fields:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#Access

The problem is - new inserted contact disappears from Contacts after about 30 seconds or so. I suspect the problem is with sync adapter, but I do not understand the cause.

There seems to be similar question, still without answer - [kitkat (API 19) inserting contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814814/kitkat-api-19-inserting-contact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for myself:
Do not add entries with not TYPE_CUSTOM type and with some data in *.LABEL field. I have added this check:

```
op = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(.....)
if (eventItem.custom_type != null 
           && eventItem.type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_CUSTOM)
    op.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.LABEL, eventItem.custom_type);
```

Comment: why not? Have you got the answer of it?

Comment: Because if there is any record (email,phone, etc) with non-custom type and LABEL field is set to some value - then sync adapter removes the whole contact. I don't know why.